# JToken Values to String

Tags: json, facebook, xamarin

I'm getting this JToken back from facebook:

```
JToken userInfo = await CurrentClient.InvokeApiAsync("/.auth/me", HttpMethod.Get, null);
```

I need to get the name and email out of this. 
I've tried several different approaches. 
Can someone help?

```
[{"access_token": "EAADnAW61F4UBAF1UBeVZCSfA5L4k9Ybx1Vi0qAZBLjZAsInqpwOfuHZCKo3yqrBoFJUfcBnr49eLlZAsxogZBZBLTVpFxAM1saXd3Dg5HobSDYoBvH3e2XAZAKGb756a6i1OVi705ZB6jOJl3rISjbOlzC2uSZAf3kwOe0GZAH385vjQAZDZD",    
"expires_on": "2017-04-30T02:17:25.7584847Z",
"provider_name": "facebook",

"user_claims": [ 
{"typ": "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier",
"val": "10155043823259643"},

{"typ": "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress",
 "val": "alex@*****.net"},     

 {"typ": "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name",        
"val": "Alex Marc"},     

 {"typ": "urn:facebook:link",       
 "val": "https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/4327859432758270/"},      

{"typ": "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/givenname",        
"val": "Alexandre"},      

{"typ": "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/surname",       
 "val": "Marc"},     

 {"typ": "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/gender",       
 "val": "male"},      

{"typ": "urn:facebook:locale",       
 "val": "en_US"},      

{"typ": "urn:facebook:timezone",        
"val": "-5"}],   

 "user_id": "alex@*****.net"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Model it, and then use JToken.ToObject:

```
var model = userInfo.ToObject<List<Model>>().First();
Console.WriteLine("UserID = " + model.UserID);            
Console.WriteLine("Firstname = " + model.UserClaims.First(p => p.ClaimType.Equals("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/givenname")).Value);
.
.
.
public class Model {
    [JsonProperty("user_claims")]
    public List<UserClaim> UserClaims { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("user_id")]
    public string UserID { get; set; }
}

public class UserClaim {
    [JsonProperty("typ")]
    public string ClaimType { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("val")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm trying your code. It's asking for a } the end of the second Console.Writeline. Take a look..  [https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_rEpmqjSkWsaTZjbU1nRG5GdWs]

Comment: Thank you! You solved it. I was a little tired last night and had the code misaligned. It works perfect. Appreciate!!